# Debugging an Object variable or With block variable not set error

Tags: vba, excel

I have this VBA code that can make prediction with given dataset.

```
Sub EIDOpredsub()
modDeclarations.initDemo                                                            'DEMO initialisieren
Dim objEachAnalysis As clsAnalysis                                                  'Zähler für jede Analyse in Sammlung
Dim rngOutput As Range                                                              'Zellbereich der Ausgabe
Dim rngInputParameter As Range                                                      'Zellbereich des unabhängigen Parameterspalte
Dim varInput() As Variant                                                           'Array für die Input-Datei
Dim varOutput() As Variant                                                          'Array für die Output-Datei
Dim varInputParameter As Variant                                                    'Array für die unabhängige Parameterspalte
Dim intEachIndepParameter As Integer                                                'Zähler für jeden unabhängigen Parameter
Dim lngEachRow As Long                                                              'Zähler für jede Zeile
Dim lngCountRows As Long                                                            'Alle Datensätze des  Reports
Dim resultCall As Boolean


On Error GoTo ErrorHandler                                                          'Abbruch, falls ein unvorgesehener Fehler auftritt

 lngCountRows = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(p_objReportActual.Reportname) _
    .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 2                                                'Alle Datensätze abzüglich zwei Zeilen für die Überschrift

For Each objEachAnalysis In p_objReportActual.Analyses                              'Für jede Analyse in Sammlung
    If objEachAnalysis.Aktiv = True Then                                            'Wenn Analyse aktiviert
        ReDim varInput(UBound(objEachAnalysis.IndepParameters, 2) + 1, lngCountRows) 'Dann dimensioniere das Inputarray
        ReDim varInputParameter(1, 1)                                               'Leere das Array der Parameterspalte

        For intEachIndepParameter = 0 To UBound(objEachAnalysis.IndepParameters, 2) 'Für jeden unabhängigen Parameter der Analyse
            Set rngInputParameter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(p_objReportActual.Reportname) _
                .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, UBound(p_objReportActual.Parameters, 2) + 1)) _
                .Find(objEachAnalysis.IndepParameters(0, intEachIndepParameter), , , xlWhole)   'Finde den Parameter im ersten Block
            Set rngInputParameter = Range(rngInputParameter, _
                rngInputParameter.End(xlDown))                                       'Dimensioniere den Zellbereich für alle Datensätze
            varInputParameter = rngInputParameter                                    'Übergebe den Zellbereich ans Array

            For lngEachRow = 2 To lngCountRows + 1                                   'Für jede Zeile
                If varInputParameter(lngEachRow, 1) = "" Or varInputParameter(lngEachRow, 1) = "-" Then         'Wenn Parameter leer oder "-" sein sollte
                    MsgBox "Zur Analyse  " & objEachAnalysis.Analysis & " sind nicht alle Daten vorhanden."     'Dann Warnhinweis
                    GoTo NextAnalysis                                                                           'Springe zur nächsten Analyse
                End If

                varInput(intEachIndepParameter, lngEachRow - 2) = varInputParameter(lngEachRow, 1)              'Fülle Input-Array mit Spalten-Array
            Next lngEachRow
        Next intEachIndepParameter

        Set rngOutput = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(p_objReportActual.Reportname) _
            .Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlToRight)).Offset(-1, 0) _
            .Find(objEachAnalysis.Analysis, , , xlWhole).Offset(2, 0)               'Finde Zellbereich für die Ausgabe der Ergebnisse
        Set rngOutput = rngOutput.Resize(lngCountRows, UBound(objEachAnalysis.DepParameters, 2) + 1) 'Dimensioniere Zellbereich für alle Datensätze

        resultCall = callEIDOminerConsole(objEachAnalysis, varInput, varOutput)                    'Übertragung an EIDOminerConsole

        If resultCall Then
            rngOutput = varOutput                                                       'Fülle Zellbereich mit Array
        End If
    End If
NextAnalysis:
    Next objEachAnalysis
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Die Berechnung wurde abgebrochen. Anscheinend ist die Analyse " & objEachAnalysis.Analysis & " beschädigt."
End Sub
```

when I debug until

`lngCountRows = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(p_objReportActual.Reportname).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 2`

it always appeared "Object variable or With block variable not set " 
What could be happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: try changing this (.Reportname)  to just . name

Comment: what is `p_objReportActual`?

Comment: 2 things to check: 1. check that `p_objReportActual.Reportname` or `p_objReportActual.name` is returning a valid value. 2. Ensure that a sheet with the name returned by `p_objReportActual.Reportname` actually exists

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "set" in front of the variable?  Like so...

"Set lngCountRows = ActiveWorkbook..."